# ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import (cv2)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pycharm

I tried 3 versions of python and deferent versions of Numpy, OpenCv-Python and I still become the same error

[image]

Comment: Did you check out the issue that the error message directs you to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by uninstalling numpy

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

and after installing the previous version of numpy

```
python -m pip install numpy==1.19.3
```